# Dynamic Routing in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js

I have a simple setup for dynamic routing using Next 13. Here is my file setup. I also have a component with an array of objects. My goal is to map over the array and show the dynamic data on the [slug] page.jsx. Aka /lion should show the data for lion.

[image]

**My Question:** How do I get the correct param or id to show the correct data on the dynamic route?

```
//Within the [slug] page.jsx

{animals.map((animal, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <Link href={animal.Link}>
      <p>Name: {animal.Name}</p>
      <p>Info: {animal.Info}</p>
      </Link>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. In the code below, the find method searches for an animal object where the Link property matches the /animals/${params.slug} value.

Here is an example of an object in the array:

```
  {
    "Name": "Lion",
    "Info": "Lions live to be 15 years old.",
    "Link": "/animals/lion"
  },
```

And here is the way I'm finding an animal dynamically:

```
import { animals } from '@/components/AnimalData';
    
    export default function Animals({ params }) {
      const animal = animals.find(animal => animal.Link === `/animals/${params.slug}`);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {animal ? (
            <div>
              <p>Animal: {animal.Name}</p>
              <p>Info: {animal.Info}</p>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <p>Animal not found</p>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js 13, dynamic routing is slightly different compared to previous versions. Instead of using the file-based routing approach, Next.js 13 introduced a new way to handle dynamic routes using the next/link and next/router modules

```
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Link from 'next/link';

const SlugPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { slug } = router.query; // Access the slug parameter from the router

  // Assuming you have an array of animals
  const animals = [
    { Name: 'Lion', Info: 'The king of the jungle', Link: '/lion' },
    { Name: 'Tiger', Info: 'A majestic big cat', Link: '/tiger' },
    // Other animal objects
  ];

  // Filter the array based on the current slug
  const filteredAnimals = animals.filter(
    (animal) => animal.Link === `/${slug}`
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredAnimals.map((animal, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <Link href={animal.Link}>
            <a>
              <p>Name: {animal.Name}</p>
              <p>Info: {animal.Info}</p>
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SlugPage;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to help. It seems things have changed a bit with Next 13. I get this error: You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.

Comment: I have updated the code according to Next 13, let me know if this worked or not

Answer (score 1):

With Next 13 you can get the params with [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) hook provided by next to search into params.

> `useSearchParams`  is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's query string.
> `useSearchParams` returns a read-only version of the URLSearchParams inter

example:

```js
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const search = searchParams.get('search')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?search=my-project`
  // `search` -> 'my-project'
  return <>Search: {search}</>
}
```

**Note that** `useSearchParams` is a Client Component hook so you have to be in a context of a client component you may need to include `'use client'` on the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks very much! The main reason I'm working with Next.js is for its SEO benefits. Is it possible to achieve this without using 'use client'?

Comment: this is not against  SEO benefits, some components have to run client side if you want to use hooks you want just to fetch data on the server

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi you since you want to show links  using `<Link>` you have to be in a context of a client component